# Trying to implement a template for a stack in c++ (and failing miserably)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, stack, lnk2019

i started studying informatics about half a year ago and we are learning [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) as a programming language, so im really new to coding. tried implementing a template for a stack today, however [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) keeps telling me "[lnk2019](/questions/tagged/lnk2019): unresolved external symbol " when trying to compile, so there must be a (probably extremely dumb) error somewhere in my code. heres the error-message(parts of it in german, words should be easy to guess though):

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public:        __thiscall stack<int>::stack<int>(void)" (??0?$stack@H@@QAE@XZ)" in Funktion "_main".
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall stack<int>::~stack<int>(void)" (??1?$stack@H@@QAE@XZ)" in Funktion "_main".
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: void __thiscall stack<int>::pop(void)" (?pop@?$stack@H@@QAEXXZ)" in Funktion "_main".
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: void __thiscall stack<int>::push(int)" (?push@?$stack@H@@QAEXH@Z)" in Funktion "_main".
```

here the code:
    //stack.h

```
#pragma once

template <class obj>
class stack
{ 
int maxSize;
int currentSize;
obj * thisStack;

public:
stack(int size);
~stack();

bool isFull();
bool isEmpty();
obj top();
void pop();
void push(obj objekt);
};


//stack.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class obj> 
stack<obj>::stack(int size)
{
currentSize = 0;
maxSize = size;
thisStack = new obj[maxSize];
} 

template <class obj>
stack<obj>::~stack()
{
delete thisStack[];
}

template <class obj>
bool stack<obj>::isEmpty()
{
if (currentSize == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

template <class obj>
bool stack<obj>::isFull()
{
if (currentSize == maxSize)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

template <class obj>
obj stack<obj>::top()
{
if (!isEmpty())
{
    return thisStack[currentSize];
}
else
{
    cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
}

}

template <class obj>
void stack<obj>::push(obj objekt)
{
if (!isFull())
{
    thisStack[currentSize] = objekt;
    cout << "Object " << thisStack[currentSize] << "pushed on the stack" << endl;
    currentSize++;
}
else
{
    cout << "Der Stack is full" << endl;
}
}

template <class obj>
void stack<obj>::pop()
{
if (!isEmpty())
{
    cout << "The Object " << thisStack[currentSize - 1] << endl;
    currentSize--;
}
else
{
    cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
}
}
```

...and the main.ccp where i tested it with a couple of integer values and found it not working

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stack.h"

void main()
{
stack<int> myStack(10);
myStack.push(1);
myStack.push(2);
myStack.push(3);
myStack.push(4);
myStack.push(5);
myStack.push(6);
myStack.push(7);
myStack.push(8);
myStack.push(9);
myStack.push(10);
myStack.push(11);
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
myStack.pop();
getchar();
}
```

help would me much appreciated, tried finding the mistake for over an hour now, thanks

Comment: For the record, "over an hour" is not a long time. Please try to spend an actual amount of time on your problems.

Answer (score 3):

Definitions of class template member functions must reside in your header file, so that they are available in every translation unit that refers to them.

Your book should mention this.